# mysqld: Could not create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL application to log to the Windows EventLog

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin, mysqladministrator

I am trying to start bin version of mysql but I run in to below error. While running from command line I am getting below trace.

```
D:\softwares\MySql\bin>mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure  
mysqld: Could not create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL application to log to the Windows EventLog. Run the application with sufficient
privileges once to create the key, add the key manually, or turn off
logging for that application.  
2018-04-11T08:01:15.926038Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).  
2018-04-11T08:01:15.928390Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0  
2018-04-11T08:01:15.933195Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.  
2018-04-11T08:01:15.933518Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue. The answer was to run cmd.exe as Administrator to allow access to the registry keys.